# Mutating an array present in one .js file from another .js file in react-native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I stored an array in a .js file as i was going to use it in number of other files. Though i got it correctly in other files (checked by rendering the items of the array) but i am not able to mutate the array as i need to add and remove items from the array.

Here is the file where my array is present;

```
export default myArray = ['first thing', 'second thing', 'and so on'];
```

And this is what i tried;

First i imported it;

```
import myArray from 'path/of/the/file.js'
```

Then tried to mutate it;

```
myArray = [...myArray , andSomeOtherItem];
```

This shows an error;

```
myArray is read-only
```

After searching about it, i think that this is a default behavior of react-native. If i am right, then how can i achieve that?

Comment: That's not a mutation! But this is `myArray.push(andSomeOtherItem);` or this `myArray[myArray.length] = andSomeOtherItem;`

Comment: Doesn't mutate mean changing the Array??

Comment: mutate means changing (some property of) some object. Assigning a new value to a local variable *(or constant in your case)* does not change the object.

Comment: In my case, when i do myArray.push(something), this is also not changing the  array but also not giving any error

Comment: Of course [Array#push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is changing the object, it's adding a new item to the array and increases its length.

Comment: Yes i got it. I also checked it by rendering the items. Push is adding items to the list. But the change is visible only on the page where i use push not other pages. Can you please explain the whole thing, how push is working here and what should i do to change this array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227690/discussion-between-thomas-and-irfan-wani).

Comment: i'd advise using redux since this is a global state-changing array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to do like that way you can try like below:

```
let myArray = require("./path/of/the/file.js");

myArray.default = [...myArray.default, "4"];

export default myArray.default;
```

This will also mutate your old array in the first file

Comment: I don't think you guys understand what a mutation is. Please read the comments above, I've explained it to OP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Took me some time to implement just because of some typos.

Answer (score 1):

That is because of it is readonly, myArray is just returning you the data, you cannot update or modify it,

what you can do is store copy in new array

```
userArray = myArray
userArray = [...userArray, 1];
```

the only way to change it will

```
export funciton myArrayfunction(val) {
myArray = ['first thing', 'second thing', 'and so on'];
 if(val) {
     myArray = [...myArray, val];
  }

  return myArray;
}

// then in your parent component

export default App() {
// pass the value you want to add in the array
 myArrayFunction(someOtherValue)

}
```

Comment: I know i can do that but i wanted to know if there is some direct way to mutate that or in other terms, change its read-only property and make it mutable.

Comment: I don't think you guys understand what a mutation is. Please read the comments above, I've explained it to OP.

Comment: Followed the first way.